# Getting a NamError when using Python and SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite, nameerror

I'm running a student database and using python 2.7 on pycharm. Here is the script

```
FirstName = input("Enter the Student's first name")
    if not FirstName or type(FirstName) != str:
    print("Enter a real name silly")
    exit()
```

and the create Table stement looks like so

```
drop table if exists StudentID;
drop table if exists FirstName;
drop table if exists LastName;
drop table if exists GPA;
drop table if exists Major;
drop table if exists FacultyAdvisor;
CREATE TABLE Student(
  StudentID int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
  FirstName varchar(25),
  LastName varchar(25),
  GPA NUMERIC,
  Major varchar(10),
  FacultyAdvisor varchar(25)
)
```

and the error I'm getting is

```
FirstName = input("Enter the Student's first name")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'john' is not defined
```

Comment: Whats the error you're seeing ?

Comment: @AK47 sorry, just updated the post

Comment: You are using Python2 I assume. Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using Python2

You need to use the `raw_input()` method when receiving String input from the user:

```
FirstName = raw_input("Enter the Student's first name")
```